# How to get examples from schema to POJOS generated via generated Pojo's via jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin

Tags: java, json, pojo, jsonschema2pojo

We have example keyword in our `JSON` schema like `"examples" : [ "001" ]`. How do I add this to the generated `Pojo's` via `jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin`. As the plugin is ignoring the examples keyword and also is there a corresponding `JSON` annotation for the example keyword?

Looked for any option in the plugin documentation but no luck.